# List modification using dictionarys (Python)

Tags: string, list, dictionary, int, negative-number

I have the following:

```
list = [['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['8763-1234-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]]]
```

.

```
reversed__dict = {'8763-1234-1'}
```

I want to write a loop that iterates over list and when it detects the reversed value held in reversed_dict to rearrange the string permanently (change to '1234-8763-1' i.e. first two segments swapped) and also multiply it's corresponding int values by -1.

I have tried the following:

```
for i, x in list:
    if i in ordered_dict:
        p = (x * -1)
return list[p]
```

But I just keep getting 'return' and syntax errors, also this does not attempt to rearrange the '8763-1234-1'

desired end result is:

```
    >>list
    >>[['1234-4321-1',[5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-8763-1', [-43, 5, 0, 0, 1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]]]
```

help much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for val in lst:
    num = val[0]
    if num in reversed_set:
        parts = num.split('-')
        val[0] = '-'.join([parts[1], parts[0], parts[2]])

>> lst
[['1234-4321-1', [5, 6, -4, 11, 22]], ['1234-8763-1', [43, -5, 0, 0, -1]], ['1234-5376-1', [3, 0, -5, -6, 0]]]
```

By the way, {'8763-1234-1'} is not a dict, it's a set. And it is not a good idea to use "list" as a name of a variable.

Also, what did you try to achieve by multiplying the list by -1?

Comment: user1532369 wanted the numbers in the list associated with the matching string multiplied by -1. It says in the question.

Comment: @User I am well aware list is not a not a variable name, I just used it in this case for comprehension.  Can I just add an extra line val[1] = val[1] * -1 inside the if statement?

Comment: Try something like `val[1] = [-v for v in val[1]]` inside the if.